# SELECT in Php with PDO (dblib) to SQL view

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to execute a SQL query and it does not work.

```
$sql = "SELECT top 5 AccountDocument from web.Preoffers_new where AccountDocument = 'xxxxxxxx'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    do {
        echo $data['AccountDocument'] . '<br>';
    } while ($data = $stmt->fetch());
} else {
    echo 'Empty Query';
}
```

This works perfectly and shows me the results.

But this:

```
$sql = "SELECT top 5 Document from Companies where Document = 'xxxxxxxx'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    do {
        echo $data['Document'] . '<br>';
    } while ($data = $stmt->fetch());
} else {
    echo 'Empty Query';
}
```

Go directly to Empty Query. But is not true because if I execute that query in SQL it works perfectly.

The only diferent i see is the first one query go to a table in the DB and the second one go to a one view...

Some clues could be this?

```
    SET 
  ANSI_NULLS, 
  QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, 
  CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, 
  ANSI_WARNINGS, 
  ANSI_PADDING 
ON;
```

**UPDATE ---->**

i set the attribute **PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION** for see if the server show me something and I received this:

**Error conectando con la base de datos: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1934 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [1934] (severity 16) [SELECT top 5 Document from Companies where Document = 'xxxxxxxx']**

I checked the error in SQL and I get this:

**%ls failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: '%.*ls'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with %S_MSG..**

Anyone have any idea why I can not make queries in views?

Thanks for reading me :)

Comment: Is your `document = "whatever"` variable? Does the document number change? If yes, you should look at http://bobby-tables.com at how to use prepared statements correctly, because right now they're totally useless in your code. You can do that with simple querys, no reason to prepare them. Also, can you show us your table structure ?

Comment: I do not understand your question. The query stores the data in an array and then displays it. It works with one of the codes but with the other not and the only difference is that one points to a table in the DB and the other to a view in the DB.

Comment: In fact, I didin't try to answer your question, I just tried to make your code safer. I just asked if this `xxxxxxxxx` document number will be hard coded in your code, or if it will be replaced by a variable, something like `Document = $DocumentID` - If thats the case, you should in fact use prepared statements. If not, there's no need to use them.

Comment: Now is a number, but of course if i use this code i chance to variable.

Comment: SOLVED: The errors given me clues.  .....the following SET options have incorrect settings...... The error does not tell me what type of configuration is wrong. I have done some tests and placing the following parameter, everything works fine:   $db->exec("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON");                                                                               
$db->exec("SET ANSI_PADDING ON");
$db->exec("SET ANSI_NULLS ON");
$db->exec("SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON");
$db->exec("SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON");

Answer (score 0):

As i see in code you use  "Document" instead of "AccountDocument" So replace AccountDocument with Document.

```
$sql = "SELECT top 5 Document from Companies where Document = 'xxxxxxxx'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    do {
        echo $data['Document'] . '<br>';
    } while ($data = $stmt->fetch());
} else {
    echo 'Empty Query';
}
```